# Getting error with SDK on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sdk, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make a windows 8 application using Visual Studio 2012. Its an RSS reader and i am using Split App - Javascript template. When i build the app i am getting this warning :

Warning : DEP0810 : This app references Microsoft.WinJS.1.0, version 1.0.8514.0, found in your SDK, but you have a higher version of Microsoft.WinJS.1.0 installed on the target machine, 1.0.9200.20602. If you continue to run this application, it will run against the currently installed version, Microsoft.WinJS.1.0, version 1.0.9200.20602. Consider updating your SDK to match the version of Microsoft.WinJS.1.0 that is installed.

I don't know how to update the SDK.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest version of the 'Visual Studio 2012 Extensions for the Windows Library for JavaScript', below:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687

I had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2013 and MS WinJS.2.0 which I updated from the following web address which resolved the problem:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40793