# Visual Studio 2013 Warning DEP0810 and Error DEP0001 with WinJS 2.1 and Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am developing my windows universal application with cordova in visual studio 2013. My **deployment target** is **Windows Phone 8.1**. In my developing process i suddenly got stuck on this warning:

> Warning : DEP0810 : This app references Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, version 1.0.9651.0, found in your SDK, but you have a higher version of Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1 installed on the target machine, 1.0.9651.40228. If you continue to run this application, it will run against the currently installed version, Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, version 1.0.9651.40228. Consider updating your SDK to match the version of Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1 that is installed. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260891  CordovaApp.Phone

with this error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030137    CordovaApp.Phone

I have already found some older questions relating this issue, but they **did not help** me:

1. [Editing the App Package Version property `SDKManifest.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274076/update-the-reference-from-microsoft-phone-winjs-2-1-version-1-0-9651-0-to-versi):

   Changing this line:

   ```
   FrameworkIdentity="Name=Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, MinVersion=1.0.9651.0"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   FrameworkIdentity="Name=Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, MinVersion=1.0.9651.40228"
   ```
2. [Installing Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JS 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673744/getting-error-with-sdk-on-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trying i could identify the issue. I have two windows phone 8.1 devices (Nokia Lumia 620 and a Lumia 930). Always switching between these two devices led into the above mentioned warning and error.

What i only had to do, was to **uninstall the related app** on the device before deploying again.